# How to get html elements value in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to add a new seller into database but all the values i get from the input text are null

this is the form

```
<div class="mb-3">
                <label for="SNameTb" class="form-label">Seller FirstName</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Snametb" runat="server">
            </div>
```

And this how i'm trying to get the values

`string Sname = Snametb.Value;`

Comment: `runat="server"` implies web forms, and if that's true you want to use an `<asp:TextBox` instead of an `<input type="text"` element. It also matters quite a bit **where** that second code snippet is located.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn You _can_ use `<input type="text" runat="server" />` in WebForms - it just means the runtime type is `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText` instead of `WebControls.TextBox`.

Comment: There isn't anything immediately wrong with the code you've posted - we need to see more to be able to tell you what's going on. Have you done  a full rebuild and/or nuked your `obj` directory?

Comment: Also... why are you using WebForms in 2022?

Answer (score 2):

You missing the closing "/> in that input box.

So, this:

```html
<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="SNameTb" class="form-label">Seller FirstName</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Snametb" runat="server" value="" />
</div>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

and button click code:

```cs
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Print("Text box value = " + Snametb.Value);
}
```

So, add the "/>" to your markup (maybe a cut+paste issue).

And not required, but good idea to add the value="" attribute also.

Answer (score 0):

add `runat= 'server'` to the text input